# Missing JDK 1.8 virtual machine on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: java, android, macos

I have mac os 10.10 Yosemite and I'm trying to install all of my tools for Android studio. I have installed the java package from apple and the jdk 1.8 from Oracle.

However, the JavaVirtualMachines folder in /System/Library/Java does not display the 1.8.0jdk.

I have simply installed the .dmg file from Oracle and run it.

If I run

```
java -version
```

I get this:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here's also a folder view of my Java installation:
[image]

Any idea how I can get the 1.8 (or even the 1.7) virtual machine so I can build in Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the JVM in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is Apple's version.

Oracle's version installs in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Comment: Thank you sir, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case i install `java_17` but latter on i uninstall `java_17` and reinstall `java_11` but its show `java_17` in `Library > Java > JavaVirtualMachines` folder ... so i run following command after deleting `java_17` from JVM folder and its work for me...  `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk`